# MPICH - mpicc-created executable not reflecting changes in code

Tags: c, compilation, executable, mpich

I'm having a bizarre problem, in which when I compile my "project_3.c" code, the "project_3" executable is not reflecting the new changes in my code.

I usually type:

```
mpicc -o project_3 project_3.c MyMPI.c -lm
```

To prove that that the new changes in my code were not being reflected in the executable, I tried commenting out a large chunk of code and writing "printf("Hello World!\n");" in vi, and then saving and closing. When I compiled and executed the file, the new changes were not reflected in the program.

**What I have tried to fix the problem:**

1. I purposely wrote gibberish letters in project_3.c to see if mpicc would detect new changes, and it did, and successfully reported an error. However when I tried making new changes to the file that did not cause an error, those new changes were not reflected in the executable.
2. I typed "ls" and viewed all files in my folder to see if there were any extra files also called "project_3". There weren't any, however there was one named "project-3", and another named "projct_3". I removed these, but the issue didn't go away.
3. I tried deleting the project 3 executable and recreating it with mpicc, but no luck with this either.
4. I made sure the compiler was not reporting any errors that would cause the compilation to fail.

I must be missing something obvious, any ideas?  What could cause an issue like this?

Comment: I would start by running with `-echo` to see what this thing is actually doing

Comment: From your description, where you stated that you erased the executable and it still ran,(assuming without performing another compile/link) I see two possibilities: 1)  that your not executing the file that you think your executing.  2) the file has a error, which is allowing it to compile, like a significant portion of the code is commented out.  and it is within that commented out portion that your making changes.  Suggest you post the code, or at least enough (compiles cleanly) to display the problem

Comment: have you been checking the times on the executable, to assure a new executable was actually being generated?

Comment: I haven't. But I will try that user3629249, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah and I can post the code too, but I'm going to try checking the times on the executable first.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem. It's actually the linux server, because a friend of mine was having the same problem with the changes in his code not reflecting in the executable. Although I just tried creating the executable again and it worked? Interesting.